# Fetch a tweet object with the Twitter gem

Tags: ruby, twitter, rubygems, sinatra

I'm using the Twitter gem in a ruby project of mine and if I retweet a tweet, I want to find that retweet belonging to me. I know this is possible by using the current_user_retweet data node documented at https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets . The issue is I have to use the twitter gem.

Currently I have this where the ID is of a tweet that I does not belong to me, but has been retweeted.

```
x = @twitter.status("590263114714714112")
return x.current_user_retweet.id
```

But the error returned says `undefined method 'current_user_retweet' for #`

Answer (score 0):

**To fetch a particular tweet by id**

`return client.status("590263114714714112", options = {})`

where `client` is the *configured object*, the string is the *id* and the options is an *empty hash* which can be configured as needed.

Source [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Tweets#status-instance_method)